# bash reading multiple text file and setting variables

Tags: bash, variables

how can read each lines and then set each string as separate variables.

for example:

```
555 = a
abc = b
5343/abc = c
22 = d
2323 = e
233/2344 = f
```

test1.txt

```
555 abc 5343/abc
444 cde 343/ccc
```

test2.txt

```
22 2323 233/2344
112 223 13/12
```

echo $a $d $f

desired output:

```
555 22 233/2344
444 112 13/12
```

Following script will set each line as variable but i would strings in each line as variable.

```
paste test1.txt test2.txt | while IFS="$(printf '\t')" read -r f1 f2
do
  printf 'codesonar %s %s\n' "$f1 $f2"

done
```

Comment: I was able to get desired output using python. I'm not sure if there is any way to get desired output using bash. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412179/reading-a-file-and-storing-values-into-variables-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the variables you want in your `read`.

```
$: paste test1.txt test2.txt |
> while read a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q etc
> do echo $a $d $f
> done
555 22 233/2344
444 112 13/12
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: this is what i was looking for.. Thank you @Paul Hodges

Comment: is there any easier way to apply same logic using python?

Comment: Python not my forté, but I'm sure there is. Post another question, tag it with Python to get the attention of the experts, and link it back to this question for reference. :)