# How do i replace source and target attributes name in a command using python. Have over 500 different attributes to be replaced

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace

The variables `var1` and `var2` in the below command needs to be replaced and replicated with over 500 unique attributes. Complete beginner in python, suggestions ?

(Plan is to read a file with 500 attributes and loop it to replicate the command with all the different attributes found in the file to a second file or print the command output in console.)

command:

```
dsconfig create-proxy-transformation --transformation-name Attr-Mapping_proxy01 --type attribute-mapping --set enabled:true --set source-attribute:"var1" --set target-attribute:"var2"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('open.txt')
for line in file:
  fields = line.strip().split()
  print fields[0], fields[1]
```

Assign values to variables var1 and var2  in above command with for loop with appropriate field values, it will do the rest of stuff.

considering in text file

```
AA11 BB11 CC11 DD11
AA22 BB22 CC22 DD22
AA33 BB44 CC44 DD33
```

Python is so easy :)

To be more specific, split() splits the contents of a string into fields delimited by some delimiter (by default any blank character, e.g. space, tab etc.), and returns an array with the split fields. strip() strips all blank characters from the beginning and end of a line. And a file in python is an iterable object which when iterated over by the keyword in, gives the lines in the file one by one. For more information on these, you can look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split , http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip , http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects .

link : [Reading a file and storing values into variables in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412179/reading-a-file-and-storing-values-into-variables-in-python)