# Making variables with for statement

Tags: python

Is there a way to make variables with a `for` statement using the variable from the `for` statement in order to add a number to the end of the variable name?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
for i in range(1,9):
    grade+i = round(float(input(firstprompt)))
    type+i = input(secondprompt)
```

Comment: See the link from @VanPeer for two reasons: First, it tells you a much better way to handle arbitrary numbers of values with dynamic names (in Python, use a list or a dictionary, depending on whether an integer index is sufficient or a static name per value is required). Second, it gives good reasons _never_ do what you're asking how to do, in any language, whether it's well-supported or not.

Comment: So... what's wrong with a list?

Comment: Also see [How can you dynamically create variables via a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop) (even though it's marked as a "dup'). In addition, there's [Python - Dynamic variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964039/python-dynamic-variables). Get the hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better for you to use `list` or `dict` object for that instead

For list

```
grade = []
type = []
for i in range(1,9):
    grade.append(round(float(input(firstprompt))))
    type.append(input(secondprompt))
```

For dict

```
grade = {}
type = {}
for i in range(1,9):
    grade["grade"+str(i)] = round(float(input(firstprompt)))
    type["type"+str(i)] = input(secondprompt)
```

Comment: The `grade+i` and `type+i` for a dictionary aren't going to work...you can't add an integer to a dictionary.

Comment: I edited the code for that

Comment: Unfortunately your edit doesn't make it work—you can't add (or concatenate) the integer value of the variable `i` to the strings `"grade"` and `"type"` like that (it raises a `TypeError`).

Answer (score 0):

I thought i wouldn't really be possible, but I realized you could use `exec` in a `for` loop to achieve that effect:

`prompt1 = 'Enter a number:\n'; prompt2 = 'Enter a string:\n'
for i in range(1, 9):
    exec('grade{} = int(input(prompt1))'.format(i))
    exec('type{} = input(prompt2)'.format(i))`

Although as Andreas suggested, a list would probably be better.

Comment: If one were hell-bent on doing this, I would not recommend exec. There's cheaper and safer ways such as modifying the namespace dicts https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373201/365102.

Comment: Yeah, I get that exec is rarely used and not that great. The question did ask for this solution, and from the link above it does say that even locals() can't edit variables even if globals could. I also mentioned it wasn't the best solution.